# How can I install and use Entity Framework Core in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I have already created the initial asp.net mvc web application template in visual studio code.
And I can run the application in a browser at localhost:5000/ 
I can also see the views, controllers, viewmodels like the previous asp.net mvc core.

Now, how can I install and use entity framework core using visual studio code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

VS Code is just an editor. It doesn't install EF (or any packages). You can install EF by editing your csproj file to contain this set of lines.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageGroup Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

VS Code may give you a prompt to "restore" pacakges. If not, call `dotnet restore` on command line.

Alternatively, on command line you can execute:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

See the ["Getting Started" guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli) for more details on EF. To use EF, you need to write code. A full example is beyond the scope of a good StackOverflow answer and is subject to change as EF Core continually updates.

Comment: Link no longer exists

Comment: Getting a 404 on the link.

Comment: The link is bad again. Please include the directions/guide/whatever in your answer instead of just linking off to a page that keeps failing.

Comment: The link refers to entity framework when using visual studio 2015 not visual studio code

Answer (score 14):

**1st :**
You need three line of code to install EntityFrameWork core and its dependencies.

**2nd :**
install them in this form

> `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -v 2.1.14`
>
> `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools -v 2.1.14`
>
> `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 2.1.14`

I put a sample of them with version but you can get latest entityframework version if you remove version in last of line.
like this.

> `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
>
> `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools`
>
> `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

**3rd**

Remember your .Net Core version should be compatible with lastest version of EntityFrameWork core which you want to install.So if you have error either you have to install lastet version of .Net Core or install EntityFrameWork core with a compatible version with .Net Core.

**Probably you are looking for EntityFrameWork core version  [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore) and also for .net Core version [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core)**

Answer (score 4):

To be able to use entity framework in visual code you can use yeoman on the terminal:

```
>npm install -g yo
>npm install -g generator-efrepo
>yo efrepo
```

Then follow the instructions

Answer (score 3):

In addition to answers given above, following article has all the steps for adding *EF Core* using *.Net Core CLI*.

[Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli/)

Hope this helps to someone.

***Edit**:
- VS Code users can execute dotnet commands from Terminal window (**Ctrl+Shift+`**)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the updated link, as of June 3.

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had deleted the "csproj" by accident, after research a lot, i knew about this possibility and found the deleted file in my trash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nuget Package Manager extension.
After installing extension;

1. Press Ctrl Shift P
2. Select Add package

[image]

3. Select the package you want to add

[image]

After selecting, it will add necesassary PackageReference to .csproj file.